# Traversal BST assignments

Tags: java

I was writing a method to print a BST in traversal order. Also, to represent the depth of each node, I wish to place a tab or "/t" string within the word to represent depth.
The problem is that when I run the code, I get the result:

[image http://neuropod.net/imagehost/uploads/9d94c563260731cb024df2801f899f3c.png](http://neuropod.net/imagehost/uploads/9d94c563260731cb024df2801f899f3c.png)

It does not print out the last element and times does not have the same indent as worst. 
I was thinking that maybe my mistake is that I am not allowing the else loop to be accessed as much as I need it to be
I expected something like this to print out

[image http://neuropod.net/imagehost/uploads/110cf543dd0f141c3ad1b9b1cb9cf5ed.png](http://neuropod.net/imagehost/uploads/110cf543dd0f141c3ad1b9b1cb9cf5ed.png)

Answer (score 1):

To print a tab, you use `"\t"` (note, that is a backslash).  `"\t"` is called an ["escape sequence"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

Comment: thank you but I was more so concerned about why I was getting different than expected results